# Grx chainring with XT/Slx RD

Tags: shimano, chainring

What with the ongoing situation with the grx rx812 rear derailleur being out of stock, I was wondering if its possible to use an XT or Slx rear derailleur with a grx chainring?

For reference I have an slx m7000 11-40 cassette and a grx 1x11 42t chainring.

Thanks!

Comment: The chain ring/cassette aren't the issue here, it's the dertailleur and shifter. What kind of a shifter do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box. Shimano road and MTB shifters pull a different amount of cable with each shift. [Art’s Cyclery](http://blog.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/) documented that Shimano 11s road shifters pull 2.7mm, and Shimano 11 MTB shifters pull 3.6mm. Thus, an 11s MTB rear derailleur will never shift correctly.

I have not used this particular [cable pull adapter by Jtek engineering](http://www.jtekengineering.com/shiftmate/shiftmate-8/), but it claims to change the cable pull so that Shimano 11s road shifters can shift MTB derailleurs, and vice versa. This might be an option if you absolutely need to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your swift response, it would be r7000 shifters but I think I'll just wait it out!